# Plotly - multiple labels on x axis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.graph-objects

I have a dataset with columns for week and month respectively, and I would like to plot variable in time using both week and month as labels.

Can something like this be done with plotly in python?

[image]

Thanks,
Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something as below:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Bar(name='Type', x=[tuple(df['Month']), tuple(df['Week'])],
               y=list(df['Value'])),
    ])
```